# Is Adobe's .getEnhancedMicrophone method for echo cancellation in 10.3 bugged?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

My code:

```
mic = Microphone.getEnhancedMicrophone();
var options:MicrophoneEnhancedOptions = new MicrophoneEnhancedOptions();
options.mode = MicrophoneEnhancedMode.FULL_DUPLEX;
options.autoGain = false;
options.echoPath = 256;
options.nonLinearProcessing = true;
mic['enhancedOptions'] = options;
mic.gain = 75;
```

In my application I am indeed using the enhanced mic, but echo cancellation still persists.

I think this is a bug Adobe needs to fix, am I the only one having this issue?

Thanks, 
Rob 
[top 100 songs](http://www.topnewhiphopmusic.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [setSilenceLevel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/media/Microphone.html#setSilenceLevel%28%29) or [setUseEchoSuppression](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/media/Microphone.html#setUseEchoSuppression%28%29)? I was under the impression that those methods were supposed to be used to toggle echo cancellation.

Comment: I also have 

    if (mic)
    {
    mic.encodeQuality = 5;
    mic.codec = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
    mic.setSilenceLevel(99);
    mic.framesPerPacket = 1;
    mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true);
    }

further below in the same method. Adobe says that setUseEchoSuppression does not do anything for the enhanced mic class.

I was also reading this article: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/acoustic-echo-cancellation.html and used the recommended settings to no avail. :(

I am starting to think this is a bug in 10.3 for the EnhancedMicrophone class.